# How does the taste of Bird Eye Chillies differ at different stages of maturity (green vs red)?

Tags: chili-peppers

What's the difference in taste between green and red Bird's Eye Chillies?

Comment: Great first question. Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much the same throughout the pepper family. The green chilis have "green" flavors - underripe, metallic, grassy. The ripe, red chilis develop more rounded, fruity flavors. You can just think of the difference between green and red bell peppers as a basic guide.